# Serverless framework uploaded image is corrupt

Tags: node.js, upload, binary, serverless-framework

I'm attempting to write a file upload service using the serverless framework that can accept binary input and store the data in S3.

The problem is that files end up corrupted in the S3 bucket. Text files do come through but my test image does not.

This is my code so far:

```
const serverless = require('serverless-http');
const express = require('express');
const crypto = require("crypto")
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const app = express();
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var chunks = [];

    req.on('data', function(chunk) { chunks.push(chunk); });
    req.on('end', function() {
        req.rawBody = Buffer.concat(chunks);
        next();
    });
});

app.put('/v1/upload', async (req, res, cb) => {
    let hash = crypto.createHash("sha256").update(req.rawBody).digest("hex");

    console.log(req.rawBody.length);
    ... s3 stuff here
```

I can see in the console that the file size is wrong; 2540872. The real size is 1395559.
I'm using curl to test the upload

```
curl -v -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" --data-binary @test/image.png http://localhost:3000/prod/v1/upload
```

Comment: When you created the lambda, AWS automatically created an API gateway for you. Go to the API Gateway settings and add `*/*` to be treated as binary. That should fix your issue. If it doesn't, perform your PUT request without setting any content type. (In addition to the `*/*`)

Obs: @gareth-mccumskey reply might be the correct way to proceed, but this is the solution to the specific issue.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this is to actually take the Lambda function out of the loop entirely for managing the upload process. S3 has a feature that allows you to generate a temporary set of credentials to allow a user to upload a file directly to the S3 bucket. This has a lot of benefits, the biggest being reduced cost of Lambda streaming binary data and billing per 100ms, as well as far more reliable uploads just in support of file sizes, and error management. What this means is that instead of the user uploading with a form via API Gateway to Lambda, the process from a frontend looks a lot more like:

1. Make HTTP request to API Gateway endpoint which triggers a Lambda function. The Lambda function then uses the AWS SDK to create a pre-signed URL and policy with valid permissions (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createPresignedPost-property). These details are then returned the the frontend client
2. The frontend constructs a form following the requirements of that pre-signed URL along with a file upload entity. The binary will then be directly uploaded to the S3 bucket.
3. At this point the frontend can then call another Lambda function (via API Gateway) if need be to kick off processing of the new image and associate it with the user or whatever else needs to happen at that point. You can even asynchronously process the image by attaching an S3 put event to a Lambda function directly (https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/s3/#s3)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm explicitly not allowed to do this. In addition to serving the file as is I also want to manipulate it in some cases. If the file is an image it should be resized and stored that way. The client should only be uploading the binary.

Comment: You can still manipulate the image once it is added to the bucket. You create two buckets. One for original images, one for alterations. As an image is inserted into one it automatically triggers the execution of the Lambda function to begin processing. That Lambda then saves the newly created image in the 2nd bucket. Upload to S3 is also far far better than any other possible upload method, even if you had a full EC2 instance to receive images. Convince who ever you need to to allow this.